# Server-side rendering with client-side reconciliation

Tags: reactjs, dom, progressive-web-apps

More a theoretical than practical question to satisfy my own curiosity. It seems to me that for webapp development you have two choices:

- **Server-side rendering**:

  - The server retrieves some information from a database, generates a new [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), serializes the new DOM to HTML and sends it to the client.
  - The client de-serialized the HTML into a new DOM. The new DOM *replaces* the old DOM.
- **Client-side rendering**:

  - The server retrieves some information from a database, serializes the response into (e.g.) JSON.
  - The client de-serializes the JSON, generates a new DOM. The new DOM is *reconciled* with the new DOM.

Besides the obvious difference of information being serialized in HTML vs. JSON, the other major difference is that server-side rendering replaces the old DOM, instead of reconciling it. This seems to me the only major downside of server-side rendering, since it forces the users to stare at a flickering screen. I would almost speculate that this is the single biggest reason why web development moved to client-side rendering at all.

**Are there any approaches out there that do server-side rendering with client-side reconciliation?**

Comment: My understanding - As our browser and processer has become more advanced so client-side rendering is smarter, faster and efficient over Server-side rendering which needs more computation to manage DOM plus network call.